# wpf need to transfer info from one textbox to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hi guys im trying to create a button which can take my information from one textbox to another but i the informationer is in Contactformula.xaml and i need it over to Mainwindow.xaml hope u understand what i mean here is the code...

```
    Mainwindow.xaml.cs

    namespace debug
    {

        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

            public ContactFormula CF = new ContactFormula();


            public object Frame { get; private set; }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }



            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                ContactFormula win2 = new ContactFormula();
                win2.Show();

            }

    ContactFormula.xaml.cs

namespace debug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ContactFormula.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ContactFormula : Window
    {


        public ContactFormula()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



        }
        }
    }
```

and here is a screenshot of the program so maybe u understand me better

[image]

Comment: I hardly recommend to have a look at the MVVM pattern. That's easy to achive when following MVVM and there are a lot of good tutorials in the web. Do yourself a favor and stop coding WPF like winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the list of contacts a static property in a static class, that way you can get or add contacts from anywhere in the program.

```
public static class Session
{
    public static List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();
}
```

you can add contacts from any page using:

```
        Session.Contacts.Add(contact);
```